# Who did Rin love romantically?

Tags: naruto

In Obito's fantasies, it seems like Rin does have feelings for Obito, but we know that she did have a crush on Kakashi.

We know that she loved both Kakashi and Obito, but whom did she like in a romantic sense?

Answer (score 6):

Rin's romantic interests are not explored in-depth in canon media, and as such, the answer to this is simply, "we do not know".

It's clear that she held feelings for both of her squadmates, but it's unclear if those feelings were more than that of camaraderie or romance.